# Fill null record on single query

Tags: sql

I have this table:

```
| ID   | PICNAME     | ECODE |
| null | 1234_22.JPG | BG01  |
| null | 2222_23.JPG | BG01  |
| null | 2345_11.JPG | AA01  |
```

I want to fill the null record with four digits of PICNAME.

The result should be like this:

```
| ID   | PICNAME     | ECODE |
| 1234 | 1234_22.JPG | BG01  |
| 2222 | 2222_23.JPG | BG01  |
| 2345 | 2345_11.JPG | AA01  |
```

How do I get this result with a single query?

Answer (score 4):

You never told us which database you are using, but if `LEFT` be available, then the following update should work:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET ID = LEFT(PICNAME, 4)
WHERE ID IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
Update 
  TBL
Set
  Id = Left(PICNAME,4)
Where
  ID is null;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `substring` to achieve this

```
update table_name
set id = substring(picname,0,4)
where id is null
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE TABLE SET ID = SUBSTRING(PICNAME,0,4)
```